# twig to tpl conversion of condition operator

Tags: opencart2.3

```
 {% set i = 0 %}

 {% set i = i + 1 %}

 {% if i % 2 == 0 %}
```

i am trying to change this set and i operator to change this code .
this is the twig file code . how can we write this code in tpl file .I am facing problem to solve condition operators like this specially f i % in above three codes  . mean how can i convert this line in tpl exactly. i am converting opencart 3.0.2.0 theme into opencart 2.3.0.2 . i tired my best to understand how to change this code in tpl but could't manage to solve it . thanks

Comment: You can convert your Twig code to PHP or TPL here : https://www.easycodetools.com/tool/twig-to-php-converter here, is online twig to PHP converter ( online twig to TPL converter )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write above code in .tpl like this

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
$i++;
if($i%2==0){}
?>
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="title_lang[{{ language.code }}][title]" value="{{ title_lang[language.code].title ? title_lang[language.code].title }}" placeholder="" id="input-title{{ language.language_id }}" class="form-control" />

above is the twig code and i converted it into tpl code . but i don't know where error coming  from "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' ".  i tried my best to figure out the issue that from where error coming but could't manage from these lines . can you please solve above . will be great for me .thanks

Comment: {{ product.date_end|date("Y") }}  and pls convert this one also .thanks

Comment: to convert `{{ product.date_end|date("Y") }}`
write
     `echo date('Y', strtotime($product['date_end']));`


and for above <input type to tpl I need your PHP code.

Comment: <input type="text" name="title_lang[<?php echo $language['code'];?>][title]" value="<?php echo $title_lang[$language['code']]['title'] ? $title_lang[$language['code']]['title'];?> " placeholder="" id="input-title<?php echo $language['language_id'];?>" class="form-control" />

Comment: and this one is my php code mam and i really thankful that you are helping me

Comment: <input type="text" name="title_lang[<?php echo $language['code'];?>][title]" value="<?php echo $title_lang[$language['code']]['title'] ? $title_lang[$language['code']]['title'];?> " placeholder="" id="input-title<?php echo $language['language_id'];?>" class="form-control" />

you have written correct tpl code.

Comment: hi . i am arslan here radhika . can i add you on skype if u don't mind please .thanks

Comment: Sure. Please provide your skype_id?

Comment: am sorry for the late reply . Here is my Skype id    arslanriaz96@gmail.com   it is link on fb and skype both else u can use arslan.riaz556    .i will wait for u thanks

Comment: Radhika r u here , i was waiting for ur msg on skype